# Alternative for google maps api?

Tags: api, google-map

We use geocodes(google map APIs) in our healthcare application to locate how far doctors and clinics are located from the patient. The locations are pointed on the map embedded into salesforce and also exact distances(in kilometres) are calculated and shown on the same page. Can we replace this mapping location solution with anything else with a cost lower than google maps API?

Comment: Yes, you can use virtually any API you can get a hold of. Did you have a specific one in mind? Can we help you?

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for your response, could you suggest Which would be the best and less complex alternative for google api's? We have a scenario in place where in healthcare section, how far patient is located from clinics and doctors is calculated and displayed on map(lightning view) using pointers. This had been setup using google apis.
What is the estimate that we can replace this using any other apis?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [Geocodio](https://www.geocod.io/). First 2,500 lookups are free, then it's just $0.50 per each additional 1000 requests.

I also liked that they have the ability to make batch/bulk requests through their API which comes in handy when trying to navigate governor limits.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind in evaluating pricing is that not all API calls are created equal. Depending on the API you're integrating against the number of calls involved can vary. The way to  evaluate the costs are to consider your workflows involving these APIs and count the # of API calls involved. From there consider the volumes.

Having said that I used [TomTom](https://developer.tomtom.com/products/maps-api) and [Here](https://developer.here.com/plans) Here is 500$ / month for 1 million API calls... With TomTom we did bulk pricing (1 million calls was 500$).

Answer (score 0):

Best alternative is **HERE JS (Geocoding Api)**

Check out this Link - [HERE JS API](https://developer.here.com/tutorials/switch-to-here-js-geocode?cid=Dev-Linkedin-YT-0-Other-TLFMNLNL-APAC-Prospe&utm_source=Linkedin&utm_medium=paidsocial&utm_campaign=Online_Up_Dev_2020)